# c++/cli using IProgress in Task

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I'm using Tasks in a c++/cli application to manage some time consuming operation without freezong the UI, as a replacement to BackgroundWorker.This is the basic usage:

```
WorkArguments ^arguments = gcnew WorkArguments(
        //some argument objects as contructor parameters
);
Task::Factory->StartNew(gcnew Action<Object^>(this, &myForm::doSomeWork), arguments);        

void myForm::doSomeWork(Object ^arguments) {
 //doing some stuff
}
```

So far, so good. My problem now is that I cannot figure out how to us the IProgress interface to provide reports of the completed work back to my UI. I cannot find the way to declare a delegate compatible with StartNew() that gets the IProcess object.

The closest thing I've found is [`AsyncInfo::Run<TProgress> Method (Func<CancellationToken, IProgress<TProgress>, Task>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779741(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1), althogh I'm not sure this is the intended usae, notevn tried it as I'm not very sure about it's porpouse,

Should I add the `IProgress` instance to my `WorkArguments` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`System::Progress<T>` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1), a stock implementation for IProgress.  All you ever need if you only want to report progress.

It does have a missing manual, it has unpleasant failure modes if you don't use it correctly.  First requirement is that you *must* create an instance of the class on the UI thread, you can't do it in the worker thread.  Store it in a field of your class before you start the task so the worker can use it.  Necessary so it can figure out on which thread the ProgressChanged event should be raised.

And you have to be careful to not call Report() too often.  Limit it to no more than once every ~50 msec, give or take.  Calling it at a high rate (more than 1000 times per second) will fire-hose the UI thread and cause it to stop updating the UI and responding to input.  Usually easy to avoid when you only call it when the reported progress value actually changes and the progress range is limited (like 0-100%).